# Assembly & Symbol of exe file from visual studio were gone after build for debug purposes

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am learning about reverse engineering on windows. I was following [Reverse Engineering and Function Calling by Address](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29527/Reverse-Engineering-and-Function-Calling-by-Addres). I did not download those source demo. I just write down a little c++ console and debug it my self with Ollydbg or xdbg64. Just for to know how windows' stack work.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void __cdecl mySecretFunction(int * param1, const char *param2,
    DWORD param3, BYTE param4) {
    // Do somethng
}

int main() {
    // Do somethng and call mySmySecretFunction()
}
```

I have [enable /DEBUG and choose Debug on Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbj9z.jpg) on App properties page.

I ran `App.exe` and it works well. I debug with Ollydbg, it can run normally, but [both disassembly and symbol of the exe are gone or missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT1yX.jpg). So I cant debug it.

So what I must to do/configurate in visual studio 2017 so I can debug my simple c++ console with external debugger like Ollydbg or x64dbg ?

Comment: What I know is that x64dbg was a debug tool for windows, I don't find a way to use it in Visual studio unless you want to create x64dbg plugin in VS: https://github.com/mrfearless/x64dbg-plugin-template-for-Visual-Studio or compiling it like this video: https://vimeo.com/213004417. If you just debug one VC++ app in VS, it would be better if you could provide the detailed information about the real issue, maybe a screen shot would be better.  If you want to get symbol for VS++, you could view the debug Module window or here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx in VS.

Comment: Ya, actually I follow this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29527/Reverse-Engineering-and-Function-Calling-by-Addres. But I don't download the source demo from that. So I write down the little c++ console and reverse that by my self. But Thank you @JackZhai-MSFT. That about x64dbg plugin seems interesting for me, and I will try first view debug module from VS. Thanks Jack.

Comment: The Debug Module window would share you where/whether the debugger loaded the symbols in VS IDE during debugging time. Anyway, if you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hi @JackZhai-MSFT, I have edited my question to improved formatting, adding image(on imgur.com), maybe you want to see them.

Comment: Not the ollydbg experts, but it seems that the real issue is related to the ollydbg usage. I didn't find the document which shared us how to call this tool in VS, they are two different tools, the real issue is that you debug one VS app using this tool, am I right?  Do you get any error or messages during you debug app using Ollydbg like this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779390/ollydbg-cant-debug-visual-studio-exe? I will keep open this case for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me with Visual Studio 2017:

1. Create an empty C++ project.
2. Add the source code you provided.
3. Go to your project properties, select *Debugging*.
4. Change *Command* to `c:\x64dbg\release\x96dbg.exe` (notice the *96*), this starts `x32dbg.exe` or `x64dbg.exe` depending on your executable architecture.
5. Change `Command Arguments` to `"$(ProjectPath)" arg1 arg2` where `$(ProjectPath)` is the previous contents of *Command* and `arg1 arg2` is the previous content of *Command Arguments*.
6. Debug the executable by launching the program without debugging (`Ctrl+F5`). If you launch the debugger like usual you will be debugging x64dbg itself, which is probably not what you want.

There is no real integration with x64dbg and Visual Studio, this simply starts x64dbg with the right arguments to debug your application from Visual Studio and you would be much better served by loading the application in x64dbg once and then manually loading it for low-level debugging.

Answer (score 0):

don't enable debug mode if you want to debug in olly-DBG. debug mode is for debugging in visual studio. in this mode you can see variables name and run program line by line. the line and varietals name have no meaning in olly-DBG. it is better that don't compile in debug mode.

you can't see your code beacuase you don't pause your program at winmain.

Go to `option` > `Debugging option` > `Events` and select `Make first pause at:`>`WinMain (if location is known)`

hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old. Anyways this's my own answer to your question.

Using the visual studio, you can integrate your debugger x64dbg to your project or current project like this.

1. You need to locate the part to your x64dbg program, either x64 or x86 version depending on the bit of the application you want to debug or build etc.

[image]

2. Provide an argument for this current project of yours. In this case, either by the full part to the executable of your project or better still in a more portable fashion, use the Microsoft macros as shown in the picture below.

[image]

And although you can provide the target initial directory for the program, but is optional. Then whenever you want to debug your application, all you need to do is just click the button and the debugger will start with the application.